# Prefill content type form field with alter hook

Tags: nodes, forms

I've created a **content type** with a **link** type field.
When an **user** add this content type I want to prefill the **link** field with the user email.
I've a create a new **module** named **prefilllink** with an alter hook :

```
function prefilllink_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dsm($form);
  switch($form_id) {
    case "job_node_form":
      $form["field_apply"]["und"][0]["value"]["#default_value"] = $user->mail;
      break;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work... Any idea?

Comment: hook_form_alter().Instead of prefilllink_alter maybe try prefilllink_form_alter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement either [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) (there's no `hook_alter()` which is what your code is implementing at the moment).

The second is probably preferable as it targets the form you're interested in:

```
function prefilllink_form_job_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  $form["field_apply"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"]["#default_value"] = $user->mail;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!
that wasn't the right hook name.
i've added a email type field and now the correct syntax is :
    global $user;
    $form["field_email"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["email"]["#default_value"] = $user->mail;